# jstl el function error on websphere

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl, websphere

I am using a similar conditional check using JSTL  in a jspx file

```
<jsp:root version="2.0" 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">  

    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:startsWith(check.defApplication, 'Mail')}">
    <c:set var="mySet" value="messages"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <c:set var="mySet" value="messagesagain"/>
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

but its throws the error

Unable to locate the el function startsWith in the tld with uri http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core

The el function is defined for uri http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions but still it gives the wrong uri in the error message. 
I changed the order in the uri declarations, but the error message remained the same.

The uri is properly defined in web.xml.
The above code works perfectly fine on tomcat, but gives error on Websphere 7.0.0.19.

Any idea what might be going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the real cause of the problem. However the following statements indicates that something is not entirely right:

> *The uri is properly defined in web.xml.*

You should **not** define them in your `web.xml`. Just having the JAR file in runtime classpath ought to be sufficient. In case, you should also **not** have extracted the JSTL JAR file(s) and put its loose contents around in your webapp's `/WEB-INF`.

---

> *The above code works perfectly fine on tomcat, but gives error on Websphere 7.0.0.19.*

Websphere ships with its own JSTL library. This conflict indicates that you've dropped the JSTL JAR file(s) in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. You'd like to remove them and put them in Tomcat's own `/lib` folder.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I removed jstl.jar and my application did not come up.However I removed standard.jar and was able to go ahead

Comment: Actually i am moving my application to websphere 7. Got a new error jsp.error.attribute.invalidPrefix  uikit. Any idea regarding this error ?

Comment: The `standard.jar` is also part of JSTL. This is also mentioned in the JSTL wiki page (if you have read it). As to the new error, this is unrelated. Ask a new question if you can't figure out based on existing Google/Stackoverflow resources.

Comment: The error comes even if I delete those jar files.However if I delete those jar files and also define the startsWith method in c.tld, then the error does not occur.Please let me know if anything is missing ? If i delete those jstl tld files, I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Check this : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=869d42f2-6ef6-4708-b5fd-dec19afe1f03&ps=25

They believe that webpshere not allow to run jsp inside web-inf